# In Polymer, How do I implement Delightful animation?

Tags: polymer

How do I implement [Delightful Design Animation](http://www.google.com/design/spec/animation/delightful-details.html)?

e.g., Animation from **menu** to **arrow**.

Which [in-built tag](http://www.polymer-project.org/docs/elements/core-elements.html) do I need to use?

[image: Step 1] [image: Step2]

Appreciate your help. Thanks!

Comment: We don't have this implemented in Polymer yet. I encourage you to post the the polymer-dev google group to get an ETA.